# Magento 1.9 thumbnail photo quality

Tags: image, magento-1.9, thumbnail

I hope you can help me to resolve an issue I am experiencing with Magento, 
When I import product images, magento automatically decreases the size to fit a thumbnail size photo, which dramatically affects the quality of the photo, The thumbnail quality is terrible however the quality of the photo once you click on the item is fantastic.

I am using Magento 1.9, which is quite a recent update so I cannot find the solution for this perticular version, 
I have found threads for previous versions like 1.4 which have the solution to them, with the comments positive saying it had fixed the issue, but It does not work for 1.9 (Unless I am doing something terribly wrong!)

I saw another thread with the same issue, but it was closed because the author did not put enough detail, 
My question is this, 
How do I improve the quality of the thumbnail that Magento automatically decreases?

I have also attached photos to show you my issue.

[image: Image 1 is the real quality of the photo when you go onto the product]

[image: Image 2 is the thumbnail size photos that magento automatically decreases to make the photo fit, quality is poor]

Hope we can get this resolved!!

Edit: The photos I've uploaded are decreased to fit the thread so the quality looks okay, If you need a link to see the site for yourself let me know!

Comment: With wich code the thumbs are put out? If it uses resize function you can try add "->setQuality(100)" at the end of that line like:
Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'thumbnail')->resize(60, 60)->setQuality(100);

Comment: Hi Stefan, Where do I put this code? "->setQuality(100)" at the end of that line like: Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'thumbnail')->resize(60, 60)->setQuality(100);"

Comment: I cant say where in your theme you have to add that code because its its theme-depended. You can turn on template-path-hints that show you where to go: https://support.sweettoothrewards.com/entries/21255937-How-do-I-turn-on-template-path-hints-

Answer (score 1):

One of the problems is, that GD makes not the best thumbnails.

You can try with this ImageMagick implementation: https://github.com/magento-hackathon/Perfect_Watermarks

Comment: Thankyou! I did see this on another thread on here, doesnt it cause High CPU Load on your website? Which is not Ideal, I saw on previous versions of magento people could simply edit the Gd2 with a code to stop it putting a white/grey background and sharpen images, is there anyway to do this on 1.9? because the code offered on other threads for 1.4 doesnt seem to work for me in 1.9, If not I'll have to try this option!

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to batch resize in a photo editing program such as photoshop.

I can't remember off top of my head what thumbnail size is (230X230px IICR)

You should upload a 1800X1800 px for main picture and bigger will slow it
and a second image to be used as a thumbnail at 230x230 please check px dimensions